# Has tinyca moved? What else to use for a private CA?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ca

I've been researching how to set up a private certificate authority for an intranet, and one of the tools I read about is tinyca.  The official web site according to Google and Wikipedia is http://www.sm-zone.net/.  This site appears to be done, and it's not just me (http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.sm-zone.net).  Has the site moved recently?  Or is something else going on with the project?

Are there other simple tools for creating a private CA that people recommend instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Tool recommendations are generally off-topic here. You can try this, though: http://xca.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this question is old, it never received a real answer.

Actually tinyCA was adopted by a new developer and is now available on its new homepage https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tinyca.

Comment: For anyone searching, this has moved again.  It is currently available at:
https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tinyca

Answer (score 8):

Try [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) - can generate proper X.509 v3 certificates, has templates for CA, server and client software, can generate CRL - pretty nice and solid software.

Comment: Is this better than TinyCA? How?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

**mkcert**

I prefer
[step-ca](https://github.com/smallstep/certificates)

another service maybe useful

https://www.ejbca.org/

https://www.signserver.org/